# Unable to submit large base64 fields using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, msxml

I am trying to submit base64 string converted file to a rest API using Excel VBA / macro. The file upload is working fine for less than 5kb files (image and pdf). There is no restriction on the server side.

**You can see the script for file upload below**

```
Sub httpPost()
    Dim xmlhttp
    Dim adoStream
    Dim image1, image2, pdfFile As String

    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    image1 = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("data:image/gif;base64," & EncodeFile(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\1.gif"))
    image2 = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("data:image/gif;base64," & EncodeFile(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\2.gif"))
    pdfFile = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL("data:application/pdf;base64," & EncodeFile(sh.Cells(i, 31).Value))
    

    Dim argumentString
    argumentString = "poster_name=" & sh.Cells(i, 3).Value & _
                    "&message_1=" & sh.Cells(i, 4).Value & _
                    "&message_2=" & sh.Cells(i, 5).Value & _
                    "&url_website=" & sh.Cells(i, 9).Value & _
                    "&email=" & sh.Cells(i, 23).Value & _
                    "&image_chart_1=" & image1 & _
                    "&image_chart_2=" & image2 & _
                    "&pdf_doc=" & pdfFile
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://example.com/api", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    
    xmlhttp.Send argumentString
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**And the base64 conversion function is**

```
Private Function EncodeFile(ByVal path As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded

    ' Variables for encoding
    Dim objXML
    Dim objDocElem

    ' Variable for reading binary picture
    Dim objStream

    ' Open data stream from picture
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (path)

    ' Create XML Document object and root node
    ' that will contain the data
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"

    ' Set binary value
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

    ' Get base64 value
    EncodeFile = objDocElem.Text

    ' Clean all
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

I have tried to find out the documentation about `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` and MS Excel. But I didn't find any field size restriction.